# How to make layout have the same height?

Tags: android, layout

Below is my layout xml code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I have 2 RelativeLayout, a and b, in the LinearLayout c.
The a and b may different height.
I want to make the two RelativeLayout with the same height which the highest one.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the property layout_weightsum = 2 in your layout c
Add layout_weight as 1 for your layouts a, b and remove the layout_height property for a, b

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope its help

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the parent `LinearLayout` height to `match_parent`. Giving `wrap_content` will fix the `LinearLayout` height to adjust to the size of it's child views.
2. Change `RelativeLayout` height to `0dip`.

Comment: But I want to LinearLayout height is 2 * max(a,b).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it automatically allots equal space for child layouts.

```
<LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Table Layout it auto adjusts it

```
<TableLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:shrinkColumns="1"
       android:stretchColumns="1" >

       <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Main Status             "
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/retentionMainStatus"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="CLICK ME" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```